# How to load multiple chrome extensions with RSelenium?

Tags: r, google-chrome-extension, rselenium

I found a way in which [one can load a single Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77912575/how-to-load-extensions-using-rselenium/77913833?noredirect=1#comment137363803_77913833) directly with RSelenium. The question here is how to load multiple extensions? Anyone?

```
  ZoteroConnector="C:/Users/Documents/URLsToZotero/Zotero.crx" 

  library(RSelenium)
  library(netstat)

  #Open browser
  eCaps <- list(chromeOptions = list(
       extensions = list(
          base64enc::base64encode(ZoteroConnector)
        )))

  rD <- rsDriver(port = free_port(),extraCapabilities=eCaps, browser ="chrome",chromever = "latest", verbose = F)
  remDr <- rD$client
```